# Parsley.js not setting parsley-success/parsley-error for custom validator on checkbox

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have other custom validators. When Parsley validates using them, it adds the CSS classes parsley-success or parsley-error as appropriate. In cases where the *only* validator is one of my custom validators, they still get the class as expected.

With this one, it doesn't do that.

I get parsley-validated, but neither of the others. Validation otherwise works correctly: If a with this validator is invalid, I get the correct error message, form submit fails, the field is focused, etc. If it's valid, I also get the correct behavior. But not the CSS class.

UPDATE: I'm getting exactly the same behavior if I use data-required="true" instead, or data-mincheck="1" (data-group is a value unique to the checkbox). In fact, looking back, I now think the CSS thing may have been why I wrote my own...

Has anybody encountered this issue? Am I misunderstanding something about Parsley?

Could it be because it's on a checkbox input?

```
myrequirechecked: function (avalue, param, self) {
    try {
        console.log("$(self.element.context).is(':checked') == %s", 
            $(self.element.context).is(':checked'));

        var ok = $(self.element.context).is(':checked') ? true : false;

        return ok;
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log("%cmyrequirechecked %s error: %s", 'color:red', id, ex.message);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful input regarding my understanding of jQuery idiom (no, seriously!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turns out to be that Parsley has different handling for radio buttons and checkboxes. The CSS classes .parsley-error and .parsley-success are meant for decoration, not for logically identifying which elements have been validated as valid or invalid.

So: options.errors.classHandler(elem,isRadioOrCheckbox) is called to determine which element will receive the .parsley-error or .parsley-success CSS class. Validation for *everything but* radio buttons and checkboxes decides who gets the CSS class like this (whitespace added):

```
this.errorClassHandler = 
    options.errors.classHandler( element, this.isRadioOrCheckbox ) 
        || this.$element;
```

...but for radio buttons and checkboxes, there's a different branch, which looks like this:

```
this.errorClassHandler = 
    options.errors.classHandler( element, this.isRadioOrCheckbox ) 
        || this.$element.parent();
```

By default, options.errors.classHandler is an empty function, so it "returns" undefined and you get this.$element.parent() for rb/cb, and this.$element for everybody else. This is what got me.

In my case, I like having the default error-state decoration (red outline) on the checkbox itself, and I'm also using the CSS class for other validation purposes, so I've written a classHandler method that always returns the element itself.

```
errors: {
    classHandler: function (elem, isRadioOrCheckbox) {
        return elem;
    }
},
```

But I also need to logically identify elements which have been passed as valid, and that's not really what CSS classes are for; you don't want your field-validity flag to be tangled up with UI aesthetics. So another (or additional) approach is to add onFieldError/onFieldSuccess listeners. They can set the error classes to your liking on checkboxes or radio buttons if you want, but more you could also introduce some unrelated method of accessibly identifying whether field elements have been validated and whether they passed or failed -- $(elem).data('parsleyValid', ParsleyField.isValid()), for example.

```
listeners: {
    onFieldError: function (elem, constraints, ParsleyField) {
        //  If it's radio/checkbox, Parsley puts these on the parent by default.
        if (ParsleyField.isRadioOrCheckbox) {
            $(elem).addClass(ParsleyField.options.errorClass)
                   .removeClass(ParsleyField.options.successClass);
        }
        $(elem).data('parsleyValid', false);
    }
    , onFieldSuccess: function (elem, constraints, ParsleyField) {
        //  If it's radio/checkbox, Parsley puts these on the parent by default.
        if (ParsleyField.isRadioOrCheckbox) {
            $(elem).addClass(ParsleyField.options.successClass)
                   .removeClass(ParsleyField.options.errorClass);
        }
        $(elem).data('parsleyValid', true);
    }
}
```